# Using GraphViz in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, graphviz

I tried to plot graphs on MATLAB using GraphViz, using this [GraphViz interface](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4518-matlab-graphviz-interface).

I keep getting this error:

```
>> [x,y]=draw_dot(G)
??? Attempted to access node_pos(2); index out of bounds because numel(node_pos)=1.

Error in ==> dot_to_graph at 94
        y(lst_node) = node_pos(2);

Error in ==> draw_dot at 30
[trash, names, x, y] = dot_to_graph(tmpLAYOUT);  % load NEATO layout
```

Whats really bugging me is that it worked great before (on my old computer).

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging, I find the solution.
Just find the line 92 in  dot_to_graph.m, as written:

```
[node_pos] = sscanf(line(pos_pos:length(line)), ' pos  = "%d,%d"')';
```

Change the %d,%d to %f,%f. Because there are float numbers in the dot file.

Comment: This issue was reported the 02/03/2010, but it seems that the code is not updated.  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4518-matlab-graphviz-interface

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to answer completely since you are not giving us the `G` you are using, so we can't reproduce your problem directly; I'll attempt to answer anyhow "on the dry":

The error messages you get mean that the temporary DOT files created by [`neato`](http://www.graphviz.org/) in [`draw_dot`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4518-matlab-graphviz-interface/content/draw_dot.m) can not be read properly; a line in the dot file which is parsed by `dot_to_graph` using the format string `pos  = "%d,%d"` is expected to contain two numbers, e.g `pos  ="42,3"`, but MATLAB's `sscanf` only reads one number from that line.

Is it possible that your new computer uses a different language setting, i.e. using a decimal comma instead of a decimal point? This *might* cause Matlab to read the two numbers as one, not sure how `sscanf` adapts to local decimal point settings.

Otherwise, are you still using the same version of `neato` as before? Could it be that its output format has changed in some way?

The best way to find out might be to set a debugging break point in the offending line 94 (`[node_pos] = sscanf(line(pos_pos:length(line)), ' pos  = "%d,%d"')';`) and check what `line(pos_pos:length(line))` evaluates to.